# Как сбрасывать значение поля в 00:00?

Tags: python, django

Доброго времени. Как сделать автоматическое сбрасывание поля? Например за день поле views набирает число 100, а как после 00:00 сделать значение этого поля равным нулю?

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Django - Set Up A Scheduled Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job)

Comment: самый простой способ - событие через cron, запускаем или самостоятельный скрипт или через manage.py

Comment: действительно ли нужно сбрасывать в 00 или достаточно первому зашедшему пользователю показать новое значение. От этого так же зависит код.